# Normal map has artifacts and nothing is fixing it

Tags: cycles-render-engine, uv, normals, baking, normal-map

So  i modeled and sculpting a Ionic column and then retopologized it, and baked the normals, but there are colored artifacts in the map. I have tried increasing the Ray Distance, the Margin, the size, but to no avail. I think it has something to do with the position, as when i select both objects and hit ALT+G my low poly drops to the cursor and my high poly doesn't budge. I have discovered a trend, the smaller the UV's are the more colored and blurred they appear. Here is trying to bake it with margin set to 64 and ray distance at 1:

[image]

Nothing really changes when i increase or decrease ray distance/margin size. Unfortaunately i cant upload my .blend file as it is a whopping 164MB. The best i can do is provide pictures:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is my UV's (on low poly, high poly doesn't have UV's)
[image]

Any idea of what could be the cause and how to fix it? Is it something with my position or not.

Comment: Have you try to set margin to 0 (as the UV parts are very close to each other)

Comment: Yes i have, the only thing it does is slightly help, but makes my map fuzzy and blurry, and also has green/yellow "sludge" around some of my UV's that are small